# Question about javascript objects

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use a jQuery plugin, the HighCharts, calling the series from a webservice but i don't know how to use the javascript javascript that i'm filling.

I've created the object like this:

```
chartOjb = new Object();
```

Then i create two properties:name and data. (i've already tested if i'm getting the values properly with alerts(); and everyting is ok).

In HighCharts examples, they fill the series like this:

```
     series: [{
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [1, 0, 4]
     }, {
        name: 'John',
        data: [5, 7, 3]
     }]
```

I've tried to do something like this:

```
series: chartObj
```

But that doesn't work. What would be the proper way to do this?
The example that i'm trying to follow is here: http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/how-to-use

Thanks

Comment: {} is shorthand for new Object() and [] is shorthand for new Array().  Always use the shorthand versions - it's a JS best practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing a single object, whereas the API wants an array (i gather from your example).  So something like:

```
series: [charObj1, chartObj2]
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you need to change is to wrap your `chartObj` in an array.

```
series: chartObj
```

changes to

```
series: [chartObj]
```

`series` needs to be an array of objects to use (one for each series.)

Answer (score 1):

```
var chartObj = {};
chartObj['name'] = 'Jane';
chartObj['data'] = [1,0,4];

var otherChartObj = {};
otherChartObj['name'] = 'John';
otherChartObj['data'] = [5,7,3];
```

Wrap these objects in an array:

```
series:[chartObj, otherChartObj]
```